# How would a military with 18th Century artillery and technology attack an enemy entrenched in a fantastical forest?

Tags: warfare, tactics

I'm writing a story in which there are large swathes of dense, magically-enhanced forests home to all manner of creatures. There's a town close the edge of one of these forests and it's being subjected to nightly raids out of the forest. Ultimately, the force sent to protect the town decides to destroy the source of the magic (a specific point inside the forest). The only problem is, there are no roads or paths leading to it. At some points the canopy is so dense as to block out all sunlight and its impossible to transport their artillery. Furthermore, there is a large population of fantastical creatures that are well adapted to the forest. Burning down the forest isn't an option either (magically enhanced and resistant to fire).

Now setting aside the wisdom of this strategy, how would you go about doing this? Is is feasible to put hundreds of men to cutting it down and making a path to the enemy?

Edit: So I've been asked to provide additional details.

**The Enemy**

The enemy force has no weapons/technology to speak of. They are an amalgam of magical beings - flying humanoid creatures slightly larger than the average man and highly resistant to physical damage; hound-like beasts that can outrun a galloping horse; extremely agile goblin-like ground force; ten-foot-tall behemoths that can shrug off rifle fire and kill with a single blow - you get the picture.

They usually attack rapidly and in small numbers, but outstrip humans in terms of physical ability (speed/strength/durability). They tend to take heavy casualties, but also cause a lot of harm.

The enemy tends to come out at night, but I imagine that once the humans begin to move into the forest, that will change. Their tactics are - once again - to attack in small numbers (40-50 creatures at a times), but emerge very rapidly, deal damage, and then retreat. They conduct two or three such attacks every day.

The forest itself poses an obstacle in terms of the difficult terrain. =

**The Defenders**
The defenders are garrisoned at a sizable town that lies on a well-developed inland waterway, so supply isn't that much of a problem. This isn't the only place that magical creatures are attacking, so the local force can't depend on too many reinforcements at the moment. They number around 800-1000, equipped with field artillery as well as heavier artillery (as part of the fort). In terms of rifles, they've moved past muzzleloaders and use breechloaders (think something like a bolt-action with five-cartidge capacity magazine).

Comment: If the magic don't stop cutting down then yes. You send thousand of men to cut the path. OR you send a band of well equipped trackers that with a mission to plant a bomb in source. Depends on your story.

Comment: You haven't provided enough details for an answer. "What strategy should I use?" is a remarkably subjective question to begin with. Without the details, it's impossible to answer based on the rules of this site (all answers are equally valid, making it opinion based). Please explain the exact configuration of the attacking force including weapons, tools, and available resources. Explain the available logistics (e.g., food supply) so we can determine time limits. Explain the defensive capabilities of the forest and its inhabitants, etc.  As is, you're asking us to write your story for you.

Comment: So I take it destroying the source of the magic is necessary to stop the raids from these creatures? Is there any reason that they can't just send a column of infantry with muskets and bayonets to reach the source?

Comment: Why can't the army just use it's own force of mages? Clearly, magic is a viable force in this world, so why aren't they using it?

Comment: The townsfolks have a *defensive* problem that does not seem amenable to an *offensive* solution with the information provided. Non-intelligent raiders (like magical-wolves) must be hunted and trapped; a military campaign against a non-intelligent foe seems clumsy and wasteful. Intelligent raiders can be negotiated with or trapped/ambushed at fairly low cost; an offensive campaign against them must have specific objectives that drive strategy. Otherwise, how will they know when they have succeeded or failed?

Comment: @user535733 -- For what it worths, the OP, unless I'm missing something, doesn't specify the intelligence or sentience of magical wolves. In any event, there are enough sophonts among the Forest Freedom Fighters to warrant use of military action. Though you bring up a good point: why wage an aggressive *offensive* war when shoring up the *defenses* should deter any but the most determined incursions?

Comment: @JBH I added some details, but the thread was closed anyways so don't know how helpful any of it was.

elemtilas Magic is a relatively new phenomenon. Most mages have only had their abilities for a few weeks/months and are only slightly more effective than a soldier.

user535733 The situation has been going on for weeks, and there's seemingly no end to the enemy. They've been trapped/killed, but that doesn't seem to deter them at all. I did state in the question that I wasn't really concerned with the wisdom of the strategy, but how to make it feasible.

Comment: @RedRobin, (a) A question can be reopened as easily as it was closed and we encourage new users to better understand why a question was closed and get it reopened. We actually love questions, but to meet the standards and expectations of Stack Exchange (and our community) we must impose rules. (b) Remember that you can only identify one "@" person in your comment and only that person will be notified. Therefore, don't address multiple users in one comment.

Comment: Finally, to complete the question, what, exactly, is the attacking army trying to achieve? We're willing to help you develop the rules of your world and/or consistently use the rules of your world - but we're not willing to help you write a story. That's kinda what you're asking (and a basic problem with "what strategy should be used?" questions). The more specific you are, the easier it is to reopen the question.

Comment: @JBH The defenders are unaware of the attacker's objective. When the defenders reach the source of the attacks, they discover a large spider-like creature connected to the forest (Wildlands); it is responsible for directing the attackers. It's control is inexact - not like a hive mind. It can issue simple commands: attack, defend, retreat. However, the creatures under its control are responsible for carrying out the commands on their own. The consensus among the defenders, based on similiar events elsewhere, is that this is an attempt to expand the Wildlands. No one knows to what end.

Comment: :-) Remember to put that in your question, not in comments. Never trust that people will read through all the comments.

Answer (score 3):

It's totally feasible to cut down large swathes of forest, humans do it all the time, often without even meaning to permanently stop the forest 'being a forest'.

If your forces have 18th century artillery, they have 18th century metallurgy, which means they can make reasonably effective saws and axes.  How long might it take to chop a tree down using such a saw?  A team of two working on a two-person saw might be able to fell a tree in ten minutes.  More labour-efficiently, you can fell trees [with gunpowder](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=uhdJAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=felling+trees+with+gunpowder&source=bl&ots=S1VbyHozRC&sig=ACfU3U2XB5yN57s4-gb4fnPbSO8rZhYbLQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia-s3gz67pAhWAQxUIHY78ChkQ6AEwFXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=felling%20trees%20with%20gunpowder&f=false), which probably wouldn't be any quicker overall but would be considerably less energy-intensive.

The density of trees in a forest varies hugely, you'd have to somewhat pluck a number for 'how many' trees you face.  1,000 trees per hectare seems a reasonable middle ground.

So felling a hectare of magical forest might require 166 man-hours of work, with or without 1,350kg of gunpowder.  For a force of a thousand men, that's only 20 mins in total (each man works in a pair and has to cut down two trees); suggesting that they could fell dozens of hectares in a day.

Note that this does not include the work needed to *clear* the fallen lumber, which is orders of magnitude more of an operation.  But if all you need to do is deny the enemy the forest as cover, you don't *need* to.  Maybe try felling a few hundred hectares, leaving it for a week in high summer, and seeing if the magical anti-fire protection wears off once the trees are dead.  Or just clear the trees off the actual narrow path you're carving towards your objective.  Or encourage timber housebuilding as the latest fashion back in the capital, and get hordes of merchants to come and clear the felled timber *for you* in search of an easy profit.

One hectare is a square 100m on a side, so if fully felled and cleared represents a clear path with a 50m killing zone either side, penetrating 100m into the forest.  It would not be at all unreasonable to extend such a path for many kilometers over a few months.